# How to read older RSS feeds

Tags: c#, rss

im doing some RSS reader (in C# , using SyndicationFeed class).
But i have a problem.

When i read for example the feed of https://stackoverflow.com/feeds, it's only the feeds of the day!
How can i read the feeds of previous day???

Thanks.

Comment: When you ask a question and get a good response, you should accept it.

Comment: @unholysampler : what do you mean??

Comment: When you accept an answer, you give people credit for taking the time to help you. You do this by clicking the check mark next to an answer for a question you asked.

Comment: This doesn't deserve to be an answer, so to whoever posts it as the SCITE shame on you... @Unholysampler ~ It is _possible_ that the feed designer put a method in to allow you to pull previous days feeds. However, that's not likely to be implemented on most platforms. Just a thought. Why don't you ask the RSS provider you're reading from for that feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Reader provides a way to get previous days answers but it requires you to login to google reader.

This will get 5 records (n=5) stating with the closest to Tue, 07 Dec 2010 21:30:53 GMT (ot=1291757453) and will show them in acsending order (r=o).   descending order would be r=d or sort by magic is r=a.

http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/https://stackoverflow.com/feeds?n=5&r=o&ot=1291757453

I think the max for this is 1000 at a time.

To get more past the 1000 barrier you need to pull the continuation string from the feed shown below.

<gr:continuation>STRING</gr:continuation>

then resend the exact same url but with &c=STRING

http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/https://stackoverflow.com/feeds?n=5&r=o&ot=1291757453&c=STRING

Not sure if this time machine will work for you but it's there.

Answer (score 7):

A feed is a document. You can read what's in that document.

You can't read what's not in that document, or what used to be in that document on a different date.

Sorry, there is no C# function that reverses time.

Comment: "Sorry, there is no C# function that reverses time." - what about DateTime.Subtract? :)

Comment: I think Microsoft should consider the reverse time feature for C# 5.0 though.

Comment: @rob You need the the implement quantumTime interface for that. So far it has been elusive.

Comment: its not possible to query the website to get the older feed? May be i should keep them in a database ...

Comment: @La Chamelle Maybe you should. But in order to put them in a database, you would have to read them while they are still online.